# Unit testing Spring Boot Repositories without test database

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Boot. I wrote a Spring Boot application and now I am trying to unit-test the repository classes. Currently, my application connects to an Oracle Database that has provided me with read operations only. I do not want to use the Oracle DB (Third party maintains the db and hence for even small permission, it takes a lot of time) as my test db either. Does Spring Boot provide any local Oracle db support for unit testing?

Note:
I thought of installing Oracle DB locally and connecting it to the Spring Boot application for unit testing. Unfortunately, the virtual box needed to install Oracle DB on Mac is not supported on my system.

Comment: You could use an in-memory h2 database or a Oracle XE testcontainer.

Comment: if the answer appears suitable, please mark it as an answer!